# Concatenate different values from a specific column to a same line

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq

I Have a DataTable with a lot of Rows and Columns.

Some of these Rows have the Same "OrderId", actually these rows are almost the same, but I have a specific value in the "TagList" Column that I have to put in the previous row.

Making a unique Row with all the TagList values inside the TagList Column.

I'll give a example below:

Line 1:
ID: 1
Name: John
OrderId: 1500
TagList: AG75

Line2: 
ID: 2
Name: John
OrderId: 1500
TagList: BG99

I wanna do it:
Line:
ID: 1
Name: Mark
OrderId: 1500
TagList: AG75, BG99

ie: Concatenate the TagList's values when they have the same OrderId.

Comment: This question wasn't clear enough for me to understand. Try editing your question to include some sample code.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? Seems it would be better to normalize the data. Have a table that holds the common information such as name and the other repeated data, and then a table that holds what is truly unique (as well as an appropriate foreign key). If you already have that and you just need this solution for some other type of processing, then so be it.

Comment: Yes, I want it. When the OrderId be the same I have to put the TagList inside the other one, ie: concatenate. It's possible?

Comment: Are you going to eliminate row 2 in your example after you've consolidated the data into row 1? Is row 2 already saved to a data repository, so you'll have to delete it there as well?

Comment: I agree with Anthony, "A man with two watches never knows what time it is". Duplicate data is bad and I'd recommend creating a second table for the tags. If you insist on a single table, you could do something like a bubble sort, except instead of sorting, it would be merging.

Comment: I agree as well, but unfortunately I really need to put in this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys, I did it, follow below if someone got the same problem:

```
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    adapter.Fill(dt);

                    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
                    String strAtual = String.Empty;

                    //Percorrer o DataTable
                    foreach (DataRowView row in dv)
                    {
                        if (strAtual.Equals(row.Row["OrderId"].ToString()))
                        {
                            string strTagNumb = row["TagList"].ToString();
                            CompareDelete(strTagNumb, strAtual, dv);

                            row.Delete();
                            continue;
                        }

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Row["OrderId"].ToString()))
                            strAtual = row.Row["OrderId"].ToString();
                    }


                    intTotal = dv.Count;
                    gvSchedules.DataSource = dv;
                    gvSchedules.DataBind();

                }



   private void CompareDelete(string strTagNumb, string strAtual, DataView dt)
    {
        foreach (DataRowView row in dt)
        {
            if (row.Row["OrderId"].ToString().Equals(strAtual))
            {
                row.Row["TagList"] += string.Concat("</br>", strTagNumb);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks folks!